# Showing that a ring is a field as well for one of the provided choices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

> Let $\mathbb M$ be one of the following rings: $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q},  \mathbb{F_9}, \mathbb{C} $. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $x^4+2x-2$. Is the ring $\mathbb M[x]/I$ a field for some of the above choices for $R$?

I have been trying to work my way around some problems involving ideals, but I get really confused when they get mixed with rings and fields. I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

In general, given a ring $R$ and an ideal $J$ of $R,$ we have that $R/J$ is a field if and only if $J$ is a maximal ideal of $R.$ Now, since each $\Bbb M$ is a field, here, then $\Bbb M[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, and so $I$ is maximal if and only if $I=\langle p(x)\rangle$ for some irreducible polynomial $p(x)\in\Bbb M[x].$ So, what you must determine is whether $x^4+2x-2$ is irreducible over any of the given fields $\Bbb M.$

**Added**: As a hint for how to address the case that $\Bbb M=\Bbb F_9,$ note that $\Bbb F_9$ has characteristic $3,$ and so $x^4+2x-2=x^4+2x+1,$ as far as $\Bbb F_9$ is concerned.

Comment: EJust as another gentle lead for fetty, three can be resolved pretty quickly with elementary facts. The trickiest one seems to be the field of nine elements. One can build the field and do the direct computations but it would be better if there is a simple way to cut the knot.

Comment: @rschwieb: I find myself puzzling over the phrase "cut the knot" in this context. Could you clarify?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks! I have added a potential "knot-cutter." ;-)